# how to check used udp buffer status?

Tags: c++, udp

I have a program that recevice message in udp in visual studio.

sometime I miss a message.I want to use select to see udp buffer used size if udp rec buffer is full.

How I can use select for this purpose?

where can I see a example?

Comment: It's probably nothing to do with the buffers, because UDP is by design unreliable. But to get buffer sizes use `getsockopt` with the `SO_RCVBUF` option.

Comment: I want to see used buffer size this can help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Post-fact discovery that your receive buffer is full will not do you any good - packets have already been dropped. Even more - you need to set your buffer sizes before `connect()` or `bind()`, they will not change after that.

What you should do is pre-set socket receive buffer to some large value that would accommodate your traffic spikes, and try to process your network input faster. That usually means doing `select()` on non-blocking sockets (or even better - some advanced API like Linux `epoll(7)` in edge-triggered mode), and draining socket input until you get `EWOULDBLOCK`.

#### Edit 0:

You cannot discover that you missed a UDP packet by using `select()` or any other socket API. This has to be done in the **application-level protocol**, i.e. one layer up from the transport. Common practice is including sequence numbers in application message header.

Comment: I did it but even I miss then I need divcovery it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`getsockopt`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getsockopt) to get socket options, including receive buffer size. Use [`setsockopt`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setsockopt) to set the size.

Example of getting the size:

```
int size;
getsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &size);
std::cout << "Buffer size is currently " << size << " bytes\n";
```

Comment: this give used size or total size ?

Comment: @herzlshemuelian Total size, there is no standard way of getting how much of it is used. If you're worried about the buffer size (which you shouldn't be unless you send enormous amounts of data and the receiving program is to slow to handle all the input) set the buffer to a larger size initially.

Comment: @herzlshemuelian And if you receive data faster than you can process it, you could create a thread that only receives data but does no processing, that threads just puts the received messages in an internal queue which another thread (or threads) then fetches from to do the actual processing.

Comment: you may need to use the 5 parameter version of getsockopt too, see https://gist.github.com/rdp/8198697

Answer (score 2):

I think one of the main properties of UDP (as opposed to TCP) is that you will sometimes lose messages.  You have to design your protocol to account for that.  I'm not an expert in UDP, but I don't understand how seeing the size of the buffer will help you, and I don't understand why you want to use `select` to do it.

Comment: I want to check if recv buffer is full incerase it.

Comment: Oh OK, that does make sense and I don't know the answer.

Comment: @herzlshemuelian That won't help much. It will just keep growing pointlessly while the cause of the missed message may be something quite different, e.g. a router overload.